# Hyperbola and limits

Tags: geometry, limits

I am working on the following question and got stuck

> On a hyperbola $f(x)$, two points $(t,f(t)), (t,-f(t))$ $\ $lie on $f(x)$. The coordinates of the two foci are given as  $F(0,5)$ and $F^{'}(0,-5)$. The difference of distance from the two foci is 6. What is the value of $$\lim_{t\to\infty}{f(t)\over t}$$ Note: $f(t)>0$

**My approach:**

To begin, I was able to get the equation of the hyperbola given in the question. Assuming that the equation of the hyperbola is $f(x)$ then, 
$${{x^2}\over{a^2}}-{{y^2}\over{b^2}} = -1$$
for a and b being constants. Using the situation given in the question, $2b = 6,$ thus giving $b=3$. Next, $a^2+b^2=c^2$, so $a^2+9=25,$thus giving be $a^2=16$. So now, $${{x^2}\over{16}}-{{y^2}\over{9}}= -1$$

Then I rearrange the equation for $y$,
$$y = \sqrt{9\left(\frac{x^2}{16}+1\right)} = f(x)$$

Now I put this into the limit

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}{\sqrt{9\left(\frac{t^2}{16}+1\right)}\over t}$$

Now I don't think my approach to this question is correct but I don't know what I did wrong. Or if I am correct, how should I compute the limit?

Comment: should it be $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is fine.  The question is really asking for the slope of the asymptotes, which you can read off from your equation as $\pm b/a = \pm 3/4.$
(The question wants the positive version.)

But you could get this by evaluation your limit:

$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{9\left(\frac{t^2}{16}+1\right)}}{t}  =
\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{t\sqrt{9\left(\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)}}{t} =
\lim_{t\to \infty} \sqrt{9\left(\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)} = 3/4. $$